# Does 'by no means' as part of the subject, require subject-auxiliary inversion?

Tags: grammaticality, inversion

Source: p 123,  *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005), by Huddleston & Pullum

> The basic division, then, is between words that modify nouns, and words that
>   modify other categories (categories of words or of larger constituents). The noun-modifiers
>   are adjectives, and the others are adverbs.<sup>1</sup> [1.] **By no means** all adverbs **`can`**
>   modify all of this wide range of head elements, but there is a significant amount of
>   overlap.

Is 1 wrong? Why did 1 lack subject-auxiliary inversion? I thought that **by no means** requires it?  [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193976/50720) didn't help. Based on [this definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/by-no-means?q=by+no+means), here's my guess of the meaning of the last sentence:

2. **By no means** **`can`** all adverbs
modify all of this wide range of head elements ...

= 3. No means exist, by which all adverbs **`can`** 
modify all of this wide range of head elements ...

Comment: *By no means* in this case is not a clausal modifier; it qualifies only *all* (= "Only some adverbs, not by any means all of them") and must therefore remain juxtaposed to that word.

Comment: @StoneyB That deserves a tiny bit of elaboration in an answer box! :)

Comment: @Araucaria As you wish.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks. I just finished it, but I'm just revisiting the harder parts.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I've finished it , erm, probably five times now - I'm still revising the harder parts too! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Oh dear, if you needed to reread it 5 times, I must do so 5^5 times ! Did you also read all of *CGEL*? I'm thinking of just reading a chapter every two days; it's dense!

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Oh, no way! I only read the bits of CaGEL that relate to stuff I'm interested in :)

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Re SIEG, no you won't (have to read it many times). It's just that when you disagree with bits, you need to really understand what they're saying to be sure that you disagree and that you might be right :) And it's fun too. Don't let it be hard work - it's interesting :) And if some bit's not interesting for you - then don't read it! That's ok too!!!!

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you, as always, for your priceless advice!

Answer (score 2):

Profs. H & P express themselves, as usual, with admirable precision.

With inversion, the expression *by no means* would modify the entire clause *All adverbs can modify all of this wide range of head elements*, leaving it unclear in what respect the assertion was being denied. By forgoing inversion Profs. H & P make it clear that only the immediately following term *all* is qualified. You might paraphrase this as

> Only some (if any—but by no means all) adverbs can modify all of this wide range of head elements.

Comment: +1 Helpful and accurate - a very unlikely outcome for this Q otherwise :) Thanks

Comment: In the OP's defense, there were a number of ways for the authors to write that sentence more clearly without sacrificing precision. It might have begun *Not all adverbs....* Surely, "By no means all ... can modify all..." is an awkward construction that leaves the reader scratching his head if not gritting his teeth. Moreover, it would be clearer to have written *every head element in this wide range* or *all of the head elements in this wide range* instead of "*all* of this wide range of head elements".

Comment: @TRomano I never accused H&P of grace! :) But I don't find it a difficult construction, and I think the *all . . . all* is deliberate and stressed. Perhaps this is a matter of age; H&P write in an academic style that was common when I was in grad school forty years ago.

Comment: @StoneyB: I noted the precision of "with admirable precision" :)